# Connecting To My Postgresql from Another Computer

Tags: postgresql, odbc

All of our machines are on the same network. I recently created a PostgreSQL database to store info. I was trying to connect to my database though ODBC on my coworkers computer but it did not work since I was using "Localhost" as the server. Can someone direct me in the right path so that I can successfully connect on his machine to my database?

Thanks,
Benny

Comment: I assume you've since changed it from "localhost" to the ip address of the postgres server. So what happened after that?

Comment: It says not accepting TCP/IP connections.

Comment: Where does it say that? Anyway things to check: your colleague's machine's firewall (is it allowing your connections through?), does postgres allow connections from your ip address (check pg_hba.conf), is postgres listening to requests from the network or only within the local machine (unless you've changed anything it will by default be fine). Most likely culprit will be the firewall.

Comment: thank you. For the server would I just put my IP address on his machine when connecting?

Comment: PG is running on your machine? I misunderstood, I thought it was on his,. In which case you need to make sure your machine's firewall is not blocking the connections. And yes, from his machine you'd put your IP address.

Comment: This article explains how to configure the PostgreSQL server to accept remote connections https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/01/23/configure-postgresql-to-allow-remote-connection.html

Comment: Thank you. The issue as 404 said was firewall blocking the port. I enabled the port and everything works fine!